# Start Visual Studio Code with WSL properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-error, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I open Visual Studio Code through Ubuntu PowerShell with "code .", I don't have instant inline syntax checking while coding. Also all filenames are white:
[First connection from PowerShell with command "code ."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii68G.png)

The weird thing is that if I click on the lower right corner and I reopen the folder in Windows: [Reopening Folder in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9A2T.png)
then if I reopen it again in WSL, finally I get the filenames colored and the inline syntax check works!

[Back to WSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH2Ae.png)

It seems it wasn't properly connected the first time or something.

How can I properly boot Visual Studio Code with [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) directly with a PowerShell command without having to switch to Windows and then back to WSL?

This is how file *c_cpp_properties.json* looks:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try; install the following extensions:

1. *[C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)*
2. *[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)*

**Note**: I guess you have GCC installed already

Comment: I have gcc installed indeed. And I should have mentionned that I also have C/C++ extension. But I didn't have "Code Runner" which I just installed, but the problem remains.

Comment: how c_cpp_properties.json in the .vscode folder looks ?

Comment: I edited my initial message with the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to WSL is probably not being properly established.

To ensure that the connection is established properly, you can try launching Visual Studio Code using the code command with the `--remote` option, like this:

```bash
code --remote wsl+<distribution_name> .
```

Using `--remote` will ensure that Visual Studio Code with the WSL instance, and should prevent the connection from breaking as easily. You should see inline syntax checking and colored filenames right away.

> **[NOTICE]** When you do this for the first time, you may get a prompt to install the WSL extension. Click install, close Visual Studio Code, wait about 10s, and then reopen it again using the same command. You may have to do this at least 2-3 times depending on your setup.

If you continue to experience issues, you may want to check your Visual Studio Code settings to ensure that they are configured properly for working with WSL. For example, you can try setting the `remote.WSL.useWsl` setting to true to ensure that Visual Studio Code uses WSL as the default terminal.

I haven't used Visual Studio Code like that in quite a while though, so the settings may be different and the `remote.WSL.useWsl` key may not exist anymore. It's worth trying though.

Comment: I tried "code --remote wsl+<distribution_name> ." a few time as you suggest but it didn't solve the problem. Also I couldn't find remote.WSL.useWsl but I found "terminal.integrated.useWslProfiles" which is set to true, dunno if this is related in any way or not. Also just in case that would be usefull, the green button in the bottom left corner always shows "WSL : Ubuntu" (it was also the case with "code .") as if it was connected properly, but the inline syntax checking is just not working unless I switch to windows then back to wsl.

Comment: @c.leblanc Have you tried to run `code .` in Windows Powershell, not in Ubuntu Powershell ?

Comment: I just installed a compiler for windows in order to try that, and it does work when opening from Windows Powershell with `cod .` (when opening in windows I have real time syntax checking without having to change to WSL then back to windows)

Comment: @c.leblanc So is the problem fixed ? Or you still want to run `code .` in Ubuntu Powershell ?

Comment: I have to code on Linux, so unfortunately the problem isn't fixed. Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing it isn't a matter of starting WSL on some powershell app or another (e.g..: typing  `wsl` > `code .`  in the cmd instead of directly  `code .` through the ubuntu app) => that doesn't change anything. What I did was typing  `code .` in a windows powershell (not going through WSL) in order to open VScode in windows => that fixed the problem. But I just did it for the test, I'm not allowed to code in windows,  hence I should use WSL (which isn't working properly).